# POST request works with POSTMAN but not in my Java application

Tags: java, api, post, servicenow

I brief description of what I'm doing, I'm automating creating incidents in ServiceNow using API. I have tested with POSTMAN first and it works fine.

Now after I wrote the code, I try to post data, I got no respond from the server. what could be the problem?

```
    if (method.equals("POST") )
            {
                url+= "api/now/table/incident";
            }
            else if (method.equals("GET")|| method.equals("PUT"))
            {
                url+= "api/now/table/incident/" + incident.getSys_id();
            }

            URL request_url = new URL(url);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) request_url.openConnection();
//            ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
            if (method.equals("POST") || method.equals("PUT"))
            {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }
            else
            {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            }

            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); // this was suggested as solution, but doesn't work.

            connection.setRequestMethod(method);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);

            if (method.equals("POST") || method.equals("PUT"))
            {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

                json.put("short_description",incident.getShort_description());
                json.put("description", incident.getDescription());
                json.put("assignment_group",incident.getAssignment_group());
                json.put("priority",incident.getPriority());
                json.put("impact",incident.getImpact());

                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(json.toJSONString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                os.close();
            }

            // read the respond
            httpsCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (httpsCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK || httpsCode == 201)
            {
                //Read
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                String lines = null;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(lines);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result);
                String incident_number = json.get("incident_number").toString();
                String sys_id = json.get("sys_id").toString();
                incident.setIncident_number(incident_number);
                incident.setSys_id(sys_id);

                return  null;
            }
```

the error is related to timeout, a posted solution suggested to set up the header to a browser type. but that's also didn't work.

Comment: Are requests to another URL possible? Firewall? SSL? Certificates? Also please post the error

Comment: the error is time out! SSL and Certificates are added to java keystore no issue related to it.

Comment: Did you figure it out by now? Are request to another URL possible?

Comment: the issue was firewall, I used wireshark to captures packet, all my packets were lost. Thanks help